# Solutions to "quadratic" type matrix equation, $\Big(\mathrm{trace}(X^TP) I + Q\Big)X = Q$?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, matrix-equations

Let $P, Q$ be a symmetric positive definite real matrices. I have an equation in the real matrix $X$ of the form
$$
\Big(\mathrm{trace}(X^TP) I + Q\Big)X = Q.
$$
I also know that $\mathrm{trace}(P) = 1$. Above, $I$ denotes the identity matrix of same dimensions as $X$.

I was wondering if this kind of equation can be solved in the indeterminate $X$. In one dimension it is a quadratic equation, and therefore the solvability is easily understood. Is there an analogue in higher dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but then what you get is a degree-$(n+1)$ polynomial equation when the matrices are $n\times n$. Let $t=\operatorname{trace}(X^TP)$. Since $Q$ is positive definite, the LHS of the equation must be nonsingular. It follows that $tI+Q$ is nonsingular and
$$
X=(tI+Q)^{-1}Q=(tQ^{-1}+I)^{-1}.
$$
Therefore
$$
t=\operatorname{trace}(X^TP)
=\operatorname{trace}\left((tQ^{-1}+I)^{-1}P\right).
$$
Let $Q=U\Lambda U^T$ be an orthogonal diagonalisation and let $S=U^TPU$. The above equation can then be rewritten as $t=\operatorname{trace}\left((t\Lambda^{-1}+I)^{-1}S\right)$, i.e.,
$$
t=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{s_{ii}}{t\lambda_i^{-1}+1}.
$$
Multiply both sides by $\prod_{i=1}^n(t\lambda_i^{-1}+1)$, we obtain a polynomial equation of order $n+1$.

Comment: Why must $tI + Q$ be nonsingular? I can see this is the case if $X$ is positive definite.

Comment: @DrewBrady The RHS of the equation is $Q$, which is positive definite and hence nonsingular. Therefore the LHS must be nonsingular too.